# Zip depended fluxes

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactor

Simplifying I have

```
var flux1 : Flux<Integer>;
var flux2 : Flux<Tuple2<A,B>> = flux1.map( id -> dbFindOperation(id) ).cache();
var flux3 : Flux<A> = flux2.map( tuple -> tuple.getT1() );
var flux4 : Flux<B> = flux2.map( tuple -> tuple.getT2() );
var flux5 : Flux<Tuple3<Tuple2<A,B>,A,B>> = Flux.zip(flux2,flux3,flux4);
```

when I subscribe on flux5, I expect that when flux2 makes each database find operation, propagation of item to flux3, flux4 and then to flux5 will be as fast, as possible. But according to log and debug info all items are loaded to flux2 at first and stream continues only after all items will be loaded.

How can I avoid this and make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Try logging how many items are requested from each flux by a downstream subscriber (this can be done with `flux.doOnRequest(LongConsumer)`. Also chapter "3.3.5. Backpressure" in the Reactor Reference Guide.

You may see how a subscriber requests 32 items first and 24 items starting with the second request. If you have no real asynchronous processing, it may request all at once (`Long.MAX_VALUE`) and simplify the processing loop (perform *fusion*).

This is controllable with `limitRate(n, 0)` operator and with `int prefetch` argument on operations such as `Flux.zip()`.

**UPDATE**

> Unfortunately neither zip with prefetch=1, nor limitRate|limitRequest=1 don't work. it still loads all items in memory at first and doOnRequest still returns 9223372036854775807.

Try `flux1.map(...).limitRate(1, 0).cache()`.

BTW, `cache()` is an unlimited cache, but looking into implementation (`FluxReplay$ReplaySubscriber.onSubscribe()`) I think that it requests `Long.MAX_VALUE` from upstream regardless of the size of the cache. (Just a guess from reading the source code. It needs to be verified.)

Regarding *your* mention of `limitRequest(n)`. Beware of it! That method name is rather misleading. -- Actually it is an equivalent of `take(n)`.

Comment: Unfortunately neither zip with prefetch=1, nor limitRate|limitRequest=1 don't work. it still loads all items in memory at first and doOnRequest still returns 9223372036854775807. flux1 contains ≈ 350 items. And for each item from flux1 dbFindOperation returns 0..1 items (Mono type)